# No `-line-filter` equivalent in clang-tidy config?

Tags: clang-tidy

I want to configure my `-line-filter=` arguments in the `.clang-tidy` file instead of in a cmake source file where the command is generated. Adding a `LineFilter` key to the file only gets me a "unknown key" error. Is this really not supported via the config file? Is there an alternative option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported, see source of [ClangTidyOptions.h](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/doxygen/ClangTidyOptions_8h_source.html)

```
/// Global options. These options are neither stored nor read from
 /// configuration files.
 struct ClangTidyGlobalOptions {
   /// Output warnings from certain line ranges of certain files only.
   /// If empty, no warnings will be filtered.
   std::vector<FileFilter> LineFilter;
 };
```