# Is it possible to ignore a header with clang-tidy

Tags: clang-tidy

I want to include a header from an external project, but clang-tidy is quite unhappy about it and produces a huge list of warnings. To workaround this, I am trying to disable all diagnostics coming from this header.

I tried:

```
// NOLINTBEGIN
// NOLINTNEXTLINE
#include <bad.hpp> // NOLINT
// NOLINTEND
```

But this does not work unfortunately.

This [email thread](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2018-May/057854.html) suggests to use `-header-filter` (HeaderFilterRegex) option.

```
HeaderFilterRegex: '^((?!bad.hpp).)*$'
```

But this results into all headers being ignored, since clang tidy [uses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39986692/1282773) POSIX regex syntax. Which [does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15377532/1282773) negative look ahead.

I also considered using line-filter for this as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56319752/1282773) suggests, but there is [no such option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64308264/1282773) for the config file.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: "Is it possible at all" is a broad question ;-) But you will most likely have some limitations. Do you use run-clang-tidy (with a compile-commands DB) or clang-tidy?
Would patching clang-tidy an option?

Comment: Yeah, judging by [this thread](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/clang-tidy-negative-lookahead-support/39007), I can replace `llvm::Regex` with `std::regex`, which should allow negative lookahead.

Comment: I suspect, the answer to my question is a "no". Vanilla `clang-tidy` does not support this yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of today (Apr 19 2022), this thread on [disclosure llvm blog](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/clang-tidy-negative-lookahead-support/39007) suggests that the feature is not supported.

Relevant notes are:

- `HeaderFilterRegex` is parsed using `llvm::Regex`, which does not support negative lookahead.
- Using `std::regex` instead of `llvm::Regex` is not possible yet, as some compilers do not have `std::regex` support. Future versions of `clang-tidy` may implement glob based file names filtering.

I can see only two possible workarounds for this now:

- List all the allowed paths in `HeaderFilterRegex`.
- Patch `clang-tidy` to use `std::regex` and use your own version.

Comment: I tried using '^.*\.hpp$' which I believe should match all hpp files. (I tried lots of other combinations including '.*'  too.

However, I see that in the "problems" window in VSCode I still see lots of .h files and .hpp files too. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @GMoney this might be a separate VSCode problem. run-clang-tidy understands such regex.

Comment: It looks like now it works, I used this in my .clang-tidy file: `HeaderFilterRegex: '^(?!(core_cm7.h|cmsis.h))'`, I use clang-tidy 18 shipped with VScode, however I do not use VSCode Cpp extension (it have half baked support for clang-tidy) but use `run-clang-tidy` instead

Comment: As of Feb 2024, the mentioned issue is still not fixed https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/25590