# clang-tidy : How to exclude third party conan packages data folder from clang-tidy analysis

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang-tidy

I'm trying to configure clang-tidy in my project folder. It's with great challenge, but so far I've achieved most of the project requirements for clang-tidy except one. clang-tidy is analysing and throwing errors from 3rd party packages in my .conan folder. I tried all combinations of `HeaderFilterRegex` and `--header-filter` possible. Some example experiments are:

- `HeaderFilterRegex: '^src/app/*|^(?!/root/.conan/data/).*$'`
- `HeaderFilterRegex: '^((?!/root/.conan/data/|/builds/).)*$'`

As suggested in [mentioned duplicate stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71797349/is-it-possible-to-ignore-a-header-with-clang-tidy), I tried without negation in regex. I am getting the similar errors from clang-tidy analysis out of 3rd party conan packages.

- `HeaderFilterRegex: 'my_project\/src\/app\/*.h'`
- `HeaderFilterRegex: 'src\/app\'`

Could anyone help me sort out this issue? I was able to filter other external libraries in other ways, but not yet filter and exclude .conan packages.